# How to move vertical scroll dynamically in Material UI DataGrid component[React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, material-ui

I am using Material UI DataGrid component in my project.
(components info : https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/)

But, I can't move the vertical scroll to selected row position like this.

```html
const windows = document.getElementsByClassName('MuiDataGrid-window')[0];

windows[0].scrollTop = 10; // 10 is for test.
```

I find that the div tag which has class name called 'MuiDataGrid-window'  has vertical scrollbar.
So. I tried that.. It doesn't work.

Does anyone know about this info?